# Can weak convergence imply orders of mean and variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Suppose we have the following weak convergence:
$$
n^{-1/2}\cdot (X_n-n) \Rightarrow X \quad \text{as} \quad n\to\infty,
$$
where $X_n$ and $X$ are random variables (note: $X$ is a non-degenerate r.v.), the "$\Rightarrow$" means convergence in distribution.

Can we prove that
$$\mathbb{E}[X_n]=O(n) \quad \text{and} \quad \operatorname{Var}[X_n]=O(n) \quad \text{as} \quad n\to\infty ~?$$

If yes, please provide a detailed proof; if no, what conditions should we add to obtain the results?

Note that, I don't want to prove the convergence in mean, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[X_n]\to \mathbb{E}[X]$, instead I just want to show the orders of the mean and variance. Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Convergence in distribution is indeed weak and $Y_n \ \xrightarrow{d}\ Y$ does not imply $\mathbb E[Y_n] \to \mathbb E[Y]$ even if $\mathbb E[Y]$ exists.

Comment: @Henry I don't want to prove the convergence in mean, I just want to show its order. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not true. Assume $n^{-1/2} (Y_n - n) \Rightarrow Y$ for some nondegenerate $Y$. A counterexample is to choose $X_n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n=2^n) = 1/n$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=Y_n)=1-1/n$. Then it holds that $n^{-1/2} (X_n - n) \Rightarrow Y$ but $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ is of higher order than $n$.

I am not entirely sure what you need to require for your proposed statement to be true. Maybe something like uniform integrability of $(n^{-1/2} (X_n - n))_n$.

Comment: thank you for your answer!